# How to change the word "WEEKLY" to "Weekly" in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ramda.js

I am getting Json data
data:{period:"WEEKLY",paidToDate: "2020-09-22"}

I want to display period in this format("Weekly")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```js
function format(str) {
   if (str.length === 0) return "";
   return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.toLowerCase().slice(1);
}

console.log(format("WEEKLY")); // Weekly
```

Answer (score 1):

With Ramda you can create a function using R.evolve that creates a new object with the updated value of `period`:

```js
const fn = R.evolve({
  period: str => `${str[0].toUpperCase()}${str.substring(1).toLowerCase()}`
})

const obj = { period:"WEEKLY", paidToDate: "2020-09-22" }

const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```